# VScode Light Themes background not changing/glitching

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can change themes perfectly for any dark themes, but for some reason when I want to switch to a light theme, the text colors change fine, but the background colors instead of turning white/light colored change to a weird grey/black theme.

I also checked my settings.json and everything seems normal

[This is what Light+ looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40NUG.png)

Comment: Welcome! 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: 3) Have you installed any extensions that make "permanent" modifications to the VS Code installation's files? Please add the output of running `code --list-extensions` in a terminal into your question post.